# R check if parameters are specified: general approach

Tags: r

I would like to include in my R functions a general approach to check if all parameters have been specified. I could do this by using missing() but I don't want to specify the parameter names. I want to make it work inside any arbitrary function. 
More specific, I want to be  able to just to copy/paste this code in any function that I have without changing it and it will check if the parameters are specified. 
One example could be the following function:

```
tempf <- function(a,b){
argg <- as.list((environment()))
print(argg)
}

tempf(a=1, b=2)
```

Comment: Personally I don't really get the question. Could you show a situation that fails for which you require a solution? I think it would help.

Comment: A function will not run if not all parameters have been provided (by default or by user).

Comment: The evaluation frame will only have objects corresponding to arguments *not* matched by `...`. If you don't mind about this, you can compare each local object to the "empty symbol": `(function(a,b,...)sapply(as.list(environment()), identical, bquote()))(a=1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this function:

```
missing_args <- function()
{
  calling_function <- sys.function(1)
  all_args <- names(formals(calling_function))
  matched_call <- match.call(
    calling_function, 
    sys.call(1), 
    expand.dots = FALSE
  )
  passed_args <- names(as.list(matched_call)[-1])
  setdiff(all_args, passed_args)
}
```

Example:

```
f <- function(a, b, ...)
{
  missing_args()
}

f() 
## [1] "a"   "b"   "..."
f(1) 
## [1] "b"   "..."
f(1, 2) 
## [1] "..."
f(b = 2) 
## [1] "a"   "..."
f(c = 3) 
## [1] "a" "b"
f(1, 2, 3)
## character(0)
```

If you'd rather the function threw an error, then change the last line to something like

```
  args_not_passed <- setdiff(all_args, passed_args)
  if(length(args_not_passed) > 0)
  {
    stop("The arguments ", toString(args_not_passed), " were not passed.")
  }
```

Comment: Glad to be of service.  If this answers your question, then click the tick next to the score box to mark it as solved.